# android what is the event after invoking third party application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm kinda new to android, i just wanna ask android what is the event after invoking third party application?

for example i have the following code to open the adobe reader to read my file from the sdcard:

```
File fileToShow = new File(passedFileToShow);
Intent nextActivity = new Intent();
nextActivity.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
nextActivity.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToShow), "application/pdf");
nextActivity.putExtra("itemName", itemName );
startActivityForResult(nextActivity, 0);
```

after opening the adobe reader and i finished reading the file, how do i call the event after i tap the device back button?

onBackPressed doesn't work,
onActivityResult doesn't work too..

thanks a lot for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pressed the back button, it's going to call onRestart (Also it should call onActivityResult with the resutlCode *Activity.RESULT_CANCELED*)

You can see the whole activity lifecyle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Wow onRestart() worked for me, thank you very much @SeRPRo! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is define a boolean which keeps track of if the user opened adobe.

```
 boolean userOpenedAdobe = false;
```

Then set it to true just prior to opening the pdf:

```
File fileToShow = new File(passedFileToShow);
Intent nextActivity = new Intent();
nextActivity.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
nextActivity.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToShow), "application/pdf");
nextActivity.putExtra("itemName", itemName );
userOpenedAdobe = true;
startActivityForResult(nextActivity, 0);
```

Then you can check the boolean in the onResume() and do something.  Just remember to set it back to false afterward:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (userOpenedAdobe) {
        // do something
    }
    userOpenedAdobe = false;
}
```

Comment: onResume was called early(before the adobe reader starts)...I used onRestart, anyway thanks for your response @SBerg413!